# Removing Extra commas from Comma delimited file

Tags: regex, perl, csv, sed, awk

I have a comma delimited file with 12 columns.

There is problem with 5th and 6th columns (the text in 5th and 6th column is identical, but may have extra commas between them)  which contains extra commas.

```
 2011,123456,1234567,12345678,Hey There,How are you,Hey There,How are you,882864309037,ABC   ABCD,LABACD,1.00000000,80.2500000,One Two
```

So in the above example "Hey There,How are you" should not have a comma.

I need to remove extra commas in 5th and 6th column.

Comment: The 4th and 7th columns always contain digits?

Comment: If possible it would be best to re-request or regenerate the csv file correctly using encapsulation on the columns with commas in.
e.g. `2011,123456,1234567,12345678,"Hey There,How are you","Hey There,How are you",882864309037,ABC   ABCD,LABACD,1.00000000,80.2500000,One Two`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always want to remove the 5th comma, try

```
sed 's/,//5' input.txt
```

But you are saying, it **may** have extra commas. You have to provide a logic how to find out if extra commas are there or not.

If you know the number of commas, you can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). This has proven to be quite an exercise, I am sure someone else will come up with a more elegant solution, but I'll share mine anyway:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

with script.awk:

```
BEGIN{
    FS=","
}
NF<=12{
    print $0
}
NF>12{
    for (i=1; i<=4; i++) printf $i FS
    for (j=0; j<2; j++){
        for (i=0; i<=(NF-12)/2; i++){
            printf $(i+5)
            if (i<(NF-12)/2) printf "_"
            else printf FS
        }
    }
    for (i=NF-5; i<=NF; i++) printf $i FS
    printf "n"
}
```

First we set the field separator to `,`. If we count less or equal to `12` fields, everything's fine and we simply print the whole line. If there are more than 12 fields, we print first the first 4 fields (again with the field separator), and then we print twice field 5 (and field 6), but instead of printing the `,`, we exchange it with `_`. In the end we print the remaining fields.

As I said, there is probably a more elegant solution to this. I wonder with what other people come up.

Comment: There should be 11 commas in each row (there are 12 columns) and the 5th and 6th columns have the extra commas.

Answer (score 2):

If all other fields are digital, you can try to save useful commas by that criteria.

```
   sed -r 's/(,)[0-9]/;/g' a | sed -r 's/[0-9](,)/;/g' |  sed -r 's/,//g' |  awk -F\; '{ print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," substr($5, 0, length($5)/2) "," substr($5, length($5)/2 +1, length($5)/2) "," $6 "," $7}'
2011,23456,234567,234567,Hey ThereHow are you,Hey ThereHow are you,8286430903,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and its `Text::CSV_XS` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my (@columns);

open my $fh, '<', shift or die;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new or die;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) { 
    undef @columns;
    if ( @$row <= 12 ) { 
        @columns = @$row;
        next;
    }   

    my $extra_columns = ( @$row - 12 ) / 2;
    my $post_columns_index = 4 + 2 * $extra_columns * 2;
    @columns = ( 
        @$row[0..3], 
        (join( '', @$row[4..(4+$extra_columns)] )) x 2,  
        @$row[$post_columns_index..$#$row] 
    );  
}
continue {
    $csv->print( \*STDOUT, \@columns );
    printf "\n";
}
```

Assuming an input file (`infile`) with three lines, where the first one has an additional comma, the second one has two additional commas and the third one is correct:

```
2011,123456,1234567,12345678,Hey There,How are you,Hey There,How are you,882864309037,ABC   ABCD,LABACD,1.00000000,80.2500000,One Two
2011,123456,1234567,12345678,Hey There,How are you,now,Hey There,How are you,now,882864309037,ABC   ABCD,LABACD,1.00000000,80.2500000,One Two
2011,123456,1234567,12345678,Hey There:How are you,Hey There:How are you,882864309037,ABC   ABCD,LABACD,1.00000000,80.2500000,One Two
```

Run the script like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

That yields:

```
2011,123456,1234567,12345678,"Hey ThereHow are you","Hey ThereHow are you",882864309037,"ABC   ABCD",LABACD,1.00000000,80.2500000,"One Two"
2011,123456,1234567,12345678,"Hey ThereHow are younow","Hey ThereHow are younow",LABACD,1.00000000,80.2500000,"One Two"
2011,123456,1234567,12345678,"Hey There:How are you","Hey There:How are you",882864309037,"ABC   ABCD",LABACD,1.00000000,80.2500000,"One Two"
```

Note that it adds some quotes but it's correct based in the `csv` specification and easier to handle that the previous state.